# Is there a javascript function to identify which endpoint is hit through fetch

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

i want to check specific endpoints which are running on specific events.

I have a function which is working fine with xhr type of request but i want to get the response with fetch type of requests and not finding a way to do that.

```
 (function () {
  var proxied = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (requestType, endPoint) {
    var pointer = this;
    var intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
      if (pointer.readyState != 4) return;
      const end_point_list = [
        '/cart/add.js',
        '/cart/update.js',
        '/cart/change.js',
        '/cart/clear.js',
        '/cart/add',
        '/cart/update',
        '/cart/change',
        '/cart/clear',
      ];

      const method = pointer._method;
      const url = pointer._url;
console.log(url)
      if (end_point_list.includes(url) && method.toUpperCase() === 'POST') {
console.log(url)
        const responseBody = pointer.response
          ? JSON.parse(pointer.response)
          : '';
        const shop_name = window.Shopify.shop;

        console.log({ url, responseBody, shop_name });
      }

      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, 1);
    proxied.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Comment: Why do you need this in runtime?

Comment: It seems like you're just duplicating what you can already do by checking the response in the Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: Note that this code is not portable. The `_method` and `_url` properties are not in the XMLHttpRequest specification.

Comment: i am building an app to track different events on the storefront of shopify stores @Konrad